# Bit flipping algorithm implementation or psuedo-code

Tags: algorithms, bit-strings

I am trying to understand and implement [Bit flipping algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2225097/bit-flipping-algorithm?newreg=de3f7e10c67b4cc29c2f7e3bc8387aec)

Can someone share the psuedocode for the algorithm and explain in detail? I cannot understand the answer.

I also want to understand what topic this question falls under (like Dynamic Programming or Optimization).

Comment: @Ross Millikan  Can you answer this question?
Thank you.

Comment: @TSR Can you answer this question? Thank you.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Can you answer this question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2225113/89922) was saying to build up the string of all $1$ incrementally from the beginning: to have first bits $1$, then to have first two bits $1$, ..., then to have the first $n-k+1$ bits all in $1$.

The algorithm is that if the first $i-1$ bits are all $1$ and the $i$th bit is $0$  (where $1 \le i \le n-k+1$), then flip the bits from $i$ to $i+k-1$ inclusive will make at least the first $i$ bits all $1$.